# display the content only in colorbox

Tags: jquery, html, colorbox

I want to display the content only in colorbox and want to disappear the content after closed the colorbox. If I add `display:none` css to the '.ajax' content doesn't display in colorbox. If add removed display the content after closed the popup. I want to disappear the content after closed the popup

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/34v22/609/)

```
<div class="ajax" >
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"/>
   <p>Hello, world!</p>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.colorbox({inline:true, href:".ajax"});
});
```

Comment: something like this  ? http://jsfiddle.net/34v22/611/

Comment: You want to remove content from the colorbox or from the `div` ?

Comment: you want to remove whole content or just `hello world`?

Comment: whole content I want to remove

Comment: @ Carsten Løvbo Andersen post ur answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onClose` function that colorbox provided.

```
onClosed: function() {
  $('.ajax').hide()
}
```

full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.colorbox({
    inline: true,
    href: ".ajax",
    onClosed: function() {
      $('.ajax').hide()

    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.colorbox({
        inline:true,
        href:".ajax",
        onClosed: function () { // Close event of colorbox
           $('div.ajax').hide();
        }
    });
});
```